# EmberJS callback on conditional template element insert

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form template/component that only shows an input field after a few options are selected, like the type of filter, and in the case of a date I would like to show a data picker on the input field, however I can't seem to be able to get a callback for just the input field without creating another view just for the input field, the template it's a simple if like this

```
{{#if showTextBox}}
  {{input type="text" value=search_term classNames="addFilterInput"}}
{{/if}}
```

is there anyway to get a callback when the input shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend ember built-in TextField view or you can reopen it. It is up to you but my suggestion is extend TextField.

```
//views/customInput.js
import Em from 'ember';

export default TextField.extend({
  onDidInsertElement: function() {
    console.log('here we go');
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});

{{#if showTextBox}}
  {{view "customInput" type="text" value=search_term classNames="addFilterInput"}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I ended up extending the input view instead but yes :D thanks